# Why am I getting an error when I try to append a DOM element to my DOM Node in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom

The error I currently get is: `Uncaught TypeError: node.childNodes.append is not a function`

Here is my code:

```
'use strict';

function textNodesUnder(element) {
  let node;
  let textNodes = [];
  let walker = document.createTreeWalker(
    element,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
    null,
    false
  );

  while (node = walker.nextNode()) {
    textNodes.push(node);
  }

  return textNodes;
}
```

That gets me all the textNodes. I then parse them to find the nodes containing my substring. I check this in a `forEach` loop. In the loop I create an image element and attempt to add it to the node but I get my error. Here is my code for this:

```
function run() {
  let textNodes = textNodesUnder(document.body);
  textNodes.forEach(function(node) {
      var myCat = document.createElement('IMG');
      myCat.src = 'http://placekitten.com/420/420';
      node.appendChild(myCat);
      return node;
    }
  );
}
run();
```

When I did `console.log(typeof node)` I found it was of `object` type.

Comment: A text node is basically a string, you can't append elements to it. You would have to append them to the parent element, at the proper place.

Comment: `childNodes` is a collection that does not have an `append` method. You want to use `node.appendChild` instead.

Comment: The code you've shown us does not even contain `node.childNodes.append `?